# Add custom PHP version 5.6.0 error to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, debian, plesk

```
VPS server
OS: Debian 10.11
MySQL 5.0.11
PHP 7.1.33
Plesk Obsidian 18.0.40
```

I added additional php 5.6.0 to make an old site work and I get the error:

> Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to
> MySQL

I am trying to install php5.6-mysql

> E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mysql E: Couldn't find any package
> by glob 'php5.6-mysql'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex
> 'php5.6-mysql'

Comment: "Could not connect to MySQL" suggests the connection information is wrong, not that the libraries for the database API you are using are missing.

Comment: And you need to remove the dependency on PHP 5 with urgency; it's been completely unsupported for over three years.

Comment: You can't find the packages because PHP 5.6 went out of support 3 years ago and the operating system vendors therefore removed the unsupported packages from their repositories. You _might_ be able to install it manually, but realistically you're a long way past the date where you should have been thinking about this. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php, https://www.php.net/eol.php . You PHP 7.1 is also unsupported btw, as you can see from those links.